# How to create a Checkbox in JMX?

Tags: java, aem, jmx

`public Map<String,String> abc(Boolean delete);`

Above is the method I declared in my interface. I am getting an input field. Based on this input, I need a check box there.

I am using `AEM` with `JMX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. Even Adobes JMX operations do not have checkboxes when they use a boolean. You always will get a textfield and then you would have to either enter "true" or "false".

Another solution would be to think about your use case and create two JMX operations without any parameters. One operation for the "true" use case and one operation for the "false" use case.

Example:

Consider a JMX operation to delete blog posts from your repository. But you want to allow the administrator to exclude blog posts of the category "Executive News".

You could have only one JMX operation that has a boolean field `excludeExecetiveBlogPosts`. But you could also have two separate operations:

`deleteBlogPosts` and `deleteBlogPostsExcludeExecutiveBlogPosts`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help